# Theoretical backing for VIF

Tags: regression, references, variance-inflation-factor

I'm giving a lecture in machine learning class covering linear regression, and wanted to briefly touch up on the idea of multicollinearity since I come from a more traditional stats background. I was wondering if there are any papers providing a theoretical backing for the VIF ,rather than simply being a heuristic method.

Comment: *The* book on this subject is [Belsley, Kuh, & Welsch](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jae.3950040108).  In one pithy paragraph (at p. 93) they provide both the theoretical basis for VIF as well as a compelling list of deficiencies.  In short, VIF was primarily of historical interest by 1980. Multicollinearity is better analyzed using other statistics.

Comment: I'll look into it. I was under the impression that it was still somewhat being used in regression especially in biomedical and psychology fields

Comment: @DifferentialPleiometry Agreed.  We have few mentions of most of the better methods here on CV and I can't think of any full account.  BK&W recommend procedures based on a detailed analysis of the SVD of a design matrix scaled to a unit column length.  They focus on the "condition indexes," defined as the ratios of the largest singular value to the other singular values.  The largest of these ratios is the classical condition number; and a careful analysis of the *several* largest can lead to a detailed understanding of the nature and effects of multicollinearity.